# Centre justification of the subcaptions

Tags: subcaption

I am using the following code to place two subfigures:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\rulesep}{\unskip\ \vrule\ }
  \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigure_1.jpeg}
        \caption[caption]{This is the caption\\Isosurface corresponding to \, $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$.}
        \label{subfig1}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \hfill
        \rulesep
        \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigure_2.jpeg}
        \caption[caption]{This is the caption\\Isosurface corresponding to \, $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$.}
        \label{subfig2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Figure 1}
        \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

The output of this code is:

[image]
As one can see the sub captions are not appearing at the center of the subfigure.

I want both the lines of the caption to be at the center of the subfigure.
I would like to have something similar to this:
[image]

Can someone please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Please show a compilable minimal example so that we can use for testing (the current one is very close to being compilable, but you also need `\documentclass`, and we don't have `subfigure_1.jpeg` and `subfigure_2.jpeg`)

Comment: I am sorry that it is a bit difficult to provide the subfigures. I am restricted in that regard. I am really sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: No problem. You can use `example-image` (or `example-image-duck` - recommended), and set `width` and `height` so that it can illustrate the size of your images.

Comment: Now I have included the dimensions in the problem description.

Comment: (Reply to comment in deleted answer) @Giri No, the problem is not the subscript. The problem is that if the caption is a bit long, the justification is lost. For now I will delete the answer and dig in it a little more.

Comment: You are relying on the single line check for centering, hence the \hspace{\textwidth}.  Zarko's solution does not have that requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red rules indicate text area borders)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=95mm}
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}
  \begin{subfigure}{65mm}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption[Short caption]{Top view.\\ Isosurface corresponding to $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$}
    \label{subfig1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfil
  \begin{subfigure}{65mm}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption[Short caption]{Top view.\\ Isosurface corresponding to \mbox{$\lambda_{2,m} = -3$}
    \label{subfig2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As previously said by @Fractal, the problem is that if the caption is a bit long, the justification is lost. My subcaption looks like `\caption[caption]{Top view.\\Isosurface corresponding to $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$}`

Comment: You might throw in a [singlelinecheck=false] just to show it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Giri, it is not clear, how you like to have centered captions, sorry. Now I guessing, that you maybe like to have centered it if they occupy just one line and centered only the last line in case of multi line caption. Or you like to have caption narrower than image? Elaborate please.

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you please tell where am I supposed to include `[singlelinecheck=false]` ?

Comment: @Giri - It is one of the \captionsetup options.  See page 9 of the caption manual.

Comment: @Giri, try `\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=9mm, justification=centerlast}`. For other possibilities cunsult package documentation.

Comment: @Zarko I would like to have the caption as seen when you run your code. But if I have the second line of the subcaption i.e. `Isosurface corresponding to $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$` the justification is lost. Where when I omit the term `$\lambda_{2,m} = -3$` I see the justification. Also I have included a screenshot about how I would like to have the subcaptions in the problem description.

Comment: @Giri, hmm, it seem, that you have problem  with math expression (it is split between two lines). Try `\caption[Short caption]{Isosurface corresponding to \mbox{$\lambda_{2,m} = -3$}}`. Is now better?
`

Comment: @Zarko, I tried. But the same problem persists.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. Does it look like `\usepackage{caption}[singlelinecheck=false]`. If yes, I am encountering the same problem.

Comment: @Giri, see edited answer.

Comment: @Zarko, you seem to have forgotten to include "Top view"  My subcaption looks like `\caption[caption]{Top view.\\Isosurface corresponding to $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$}`

Comment: @gire - Not if you also include [justification=centering].  The single line check puts the entire caption into an \hbox and checks the width.  If it is less than \hsize then it will fit into one line and gets centered.  If not, it is formatted normally.

Comment: @Giri, sorry, I didn't forget anything. This is not mentioned anywhere in your question and unfortunately, my crystal ball is in service ... :-)

Comment: @Zarko, yes it is not mentioned in the question. But I have mentioned in the first comment appearing below your answer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I have not included [justification = centring]. Still I see the error. It would be very helpful if you can provide a small snippet of the code, in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Giri, please edit your question  and clarify what you like to have. Additional information in comments are less visible to audience. Also show, what you obtain with your code and make clear, what you like to have. So far we run in circle ...

Comment: @ Zarko. Thanks a ton!. I am really sorry for the confusion caused. I will edit my question.

Comment: More precisely, [singlelinecheck=false] replaces \hspace{\textwidth} as way way to turn OFF centering.  [justification=centering] turns it back on again.